# HttpClient.PostAsync() to Identity LogOut gets a 400

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to programmatically post to https://localhost:7229/identity/account/LogOut to force an Identity library logout. The use case is in my code I have disabled a user in the Identity DB and I need to now force them to logout.

The following does work. This is the menu item where the user chooses to logout:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject Services.TokenProvider TokenProvider

<form action="/identity/account/logout" method="post">
    <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" type="submit">
        <span class="oi oi-account-logout" aria-hidden="true"></span> Log out (@context.User.Identity?.Name)
    </button>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"
           value="@TokenProvider.XsrfToken">
</form>
```

So I did the following to force the logout:

```
private async Task ForceLogout()
{
    var url = new Uri(new Uri(NavigationManager.BaseUri), "/identity/account/LogOut").ToString();
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    data.Add("__RequestVerificationToken", TokenProvider.XsrfToken);
    await HttpUtilities.PostPageAsync(url, data);
}
```

And here's the utility method:

```
public static async Task<string> PostPageAsync(string url, IDictionary<string, string> data)
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseBody;
        }

        return response.StatusCode.ToString();
    }
}
```

What is it unhappy with in this request?

---

I ran this under Fiddler and on a Logout (via the menu above that works) it then has the following requests:

```
GET https://localhost:7229/_blazor?id=bk3aitwu0pt61wN2lTT-Hg
GET http://localhost:61757/eee0db2370724e1392ebbae5ce488891/browserLinkSignalR/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAQYboKXN8pEu41dvuClBLmAAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAADEgkdE1H%2FtaEgAz4c5WnPWh9J8ZdYng3xUq8tzh2563wAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAD%2FqRqzTlh%2FS4P8DvSXJefPJg54hdErDPargmKjlPtuQjAAAABWQ%2B%2BAyUHfWPMqeogPRh%2FFKKAFQATZRQkqYHnoGt5qOQHwb8u%2BILMdq8KILdENeSxAAAAAuu%2BhBhiPHVZ0V5oBNnCBw7PWxJ2Rw9A2%2FbUI6%2FZLo8M0%2FrIfBQstaKaYmYuPUOQkWe2NEZVXzkhn8GS%2B35LGmw%3D%3D&requestUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7229%2F&browserName=&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64)+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2F114.0.0.0+Safari%2F537.36&browserIdKey=window.browserLink.initializationData.browserId&browserId=89f0-8194&tid=10
GET https://localhost:44342/LouisHowe.web/
GET http://localhost:61757/eee0db2370724e1392ebbae5ce488891/browserLinkSignalR/negotiate?requestUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7229%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FLogout&browserName=&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64)+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2F114.0.0.0+Safari%2F537.36&browserIdKey=window.browserLink.initializationData.browserId&browserId=dec7-7060&clientProtocol=1.3&_=1687795004382
CONNECT http://localhost:61757
GET http://localhost:61757/eee0db2370724e1392ebbae5ce488891/browserLinkSignalR/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAQYboKXN8pEu41dvuClBLmAAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAAAZw1PagtFY%2FzmUOqLeNXl7HOKcw9RNJaCykI0sqoBnlwAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAADHRNc0GdIBXXTrKqnijY73mqxEi9rLXE4tzyAFRRJRzzAAAACZqmPElteVam4WkF3icse6nsgvHkRoQs8iP46aMx%2FEeDGZklowApVQ0xBze8pRZvJAAAAAi1LUgMAjfJ5A83T99UTHc7WQaeyX1WwSMM5R7v8wiSWw%2FwqZ%2FJsg9ZREWLNK9XWzYBadSwqnsWdfjHpgzw%2FrtQ%3D%3D&requestUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7229%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FLogout&browserName=&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64)+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2F114.0.0.0+Safari%2F537.36&browserIdKey=window.browserLink.initializationData.browserId&browserId=dec7-7060&tid=6
CONNECT http://localhost:44342
GET https://localhost:44342/LouisHowe.web/
```

So first off very weird that there is no POST. I did it three times, no POST. Second, some of this is SignalR because this is a Blazor server-side app, but the logout page is MVC from the ASP.NET Identity library.

That very first request to `https://localhost:7229/_blazor?id=bk3aitwu0pt61wN2lTT-Hg` - where does the `_blazor?id=bk3aitwu0pt61wN2lTT-Hg` part come from?

And the `<form action="/identity/account/logout` - there never is a request to `/identity/account/logout` so why is the `<form>` not doing a post and not making a request to `/identity/account/logout`?

In that first GET there is a single param of id=bk3aitwu0pt61wN2lTT-Hg and there are three cookies:

```
 1. DXBZCurrentTheme=blazing-berry
 2. .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.NTOTRZh9YkQ=CfDJ8At45xHXlM5DiXhbQyX7rG-pPsHk1NqH9oZMMR-KZ-wiGNnGBg1KOmCRWUSo6YAXS-o8kwT6hh8AV8WM6KjnQR5cbRWOJg_13GujxmSWlUcRDzmlYEPRnDqg-aQxi_bRukCAPEqmlZdEPcQSCzx4Qyg
 3. .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8At45xHXlM5DiXhbQyX7rG80oI2kYPn2qnM8h-7owpZo1iSahCZKa3uwfM_H_YOmFuH-vIp_LWgr_iGWUGIpJItLs40IFe1444Dv9FoMHR7LOv7dEbLmmCvXn-D6ntZXb6WhFCUiMAIUIzy9FwQm7W41AbJCjNy-AQ4jN2wPk1xEfDXSJAtVFj64yQ1tUzLDewplMcrEmh3jml0qe3npU7Ue67-_2Ckev1b0SqK1D8bPrW7EiS7MoGk0NK9dRfKuKGFfw46luGkNeRTXdOTEFhym6LqVF8n_hxygalJXsZcFIRlDVztG7WWFOVk5LpG_5rtnDTklWQRd_nszFZv9f3CPogEaaVaKsNV-meJ6blxUw4odsP7SUotvV64w-yGaK5ysFpErjJftajtaeV_G-P60lSIDKU2ZSji1GIxLmueDdV71Azici5cG20DtUHZd8qR-jKcGyXKV-T4d3gtxwnfim6uCF4r2dnkho5T6aUNqqPVQkE8hoi3hkspQ-bzzvJ1T4qE880uoV3pWWWfVjlJYdPGpZU1ghUUOfWb8p0IfzjWGxCi23MiONcp_B7S-HRUes_bukTMzVFReyYI97_ycenpbFo4Q4MI-OPrS1YyjYi1t1PCIBzrOxWhKfFRf2xnqW3rFmi1YDw2UEtrdKCPnuD9fmN28j5CtmS0pEASF6gJQ7Nnz9tTEdAWwnYLgiQGZPnuuClmdACnkj6ZEfZXYttjKjkbum5CVIbd0Bf7WBaBqzXosRD8fzgkEfaGazVjyJTnj2pONmR0w0lwj6R8n4jn45ojUicl9v2oSjUbP4wsRr-paK_pJs_eWsLRKZyZAhm89GV1QY22KyZ8rxQKtRVuMBCySy4vhCdI8wQec_LJTH_jVSTaA3QOqwfJtK3VhMbg5tPUnfS5qgjC-_dU8cZi03CwTFro5FEa2jhRM1aXnRrhq2PCBsRMjzOI3TPg71yUN2XmBE8lrJSAxpSh3_cRg5y3oMzgLh6CB6MYvxL8fxSKjUBCuZRGE6d60lg
```

Do I need to somehow figure out what these are and pass them too?